# jQuery group elements and create select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Ok here's what i have

```
<div>
 <h2 class="type">A</h2>
 <p class="value">12</p>
</div>

<div>
 <h2 class="type">A</h2>
 <p class="value">24</p>
</div>

<div>
 <h2 class="type">B</h2>
 <p class="value">35</p>
</div>
```

And what i want to do is go through them, group them and create a select dropdown like this:

```
<select>
 <option value="12,24">A</option>
 <option value="35">B</option>
</select>
```

How would you approach that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: IKR? They just ask us to write their code.

Comment: No i didn't try anything and i could be more than happy even with the first paragraph of BoltClock.

Comment: @tsiger: Oh, no problem. Like I said, I provided the code only because I felt like it :) Glad I helped, been a long day for me now...

Comment: Thanx man :) hope you will get some rest :)
I guess the downvote was for not providing something as a base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I felt like writing some jQuery code tonight for kicks before I go to bed.

Basically, iterate through your `<div>`s and make an object of arrays out of their types and values. After that, make a `<select>`, iterate through the object and add dropdown `<option>`s containing its types and values.

```
var types = {};

$('div').each(function() {
    var type = $('.type', this).text();
    var value = $('.value', this).text();
    if (!types[type]) types[type] = [];

    types[type].push(value);
});

var select = $('<select></select>');

$.each(types, function(i, v) {
    select.append('<option value="' + v + '">' + i + '</option>');
});

select.appendTo('body');
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/9BKpr/8)

Comment: See, I would have guessed you'd use Javascript.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Not really understanding your jQuery/JS comment, I must be really tired. Care to elaborate? *edit* Looked at it again and there sure is plenty of plain JS in there, if that's what you were referring to.

Comment: It was a joke, considering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var options;

$("p.type").each(function(i, el){
    el = $(el);
    var value = el.siblings("p.value").text();

    if(options[el.text()] == null){
        options[el.text()] = [value];
    } else { options[el.text()].push(value); }
});
```

Now you have the them in `options` for easy manipulation.